# Как проиндексировать (добавить) сразу все удаленные файлы?

Tags: git, git-add, git-commit

Удалил в проекте папку, в ней, допустим, 1000 файлов.

Пишу

```
git status
```

в ответ

```
deleted:    "public/..."  
...  
1000 раз  
...  
deleted:    "public/..."
```

Ну, понятное дело, что писать 1000 раз

```
git checkout -- public/...
```

не серьезно.

Вот, собственно, и вопрос.
Подскажите команду для, например, удаления всего удаленного.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Гит оперирует файлами, директорий для него нет как сущности, поэтому он выводит всю тысячу удаленных файлов. Для востановления папки попробуйте ее и написать (git checkout -- public), я не уверен, что сработает, но возможно. Альтернативный вариант - git checkout -- public/*, но, опять же, никогда вообще с такой потребностью не сталкивался.

Comment: Не согласен с принятым ответом, т.к. он содержит ошибку и выполняет другую (более широкую) задачу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так вы уже удалили файлы. Теперь нужно сделать коммит и отправить на сервер.

```
git add . && git commit -m "Delete files" && git push
```

И все. Все что Вы удалили, удалится и из репозитория. Или же Вам нужно восстановить что удалили?

Comment: Да, я здорово лажал до сего момента.  
Почему то руками удалял, думал, что эти удаленные в статусе будут пока не удалишь)))  
И проверить же не судьба была.

Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

## Как исправить

Чтобы индексировать *только все удаленные* файлы:

```
git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm
```

Для индексирования  *всех удаленных + всех обновленных* файлов можно использовать [параметр `-u`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431840/181472):

```
git add -u
```

Потом на основе этих файлов делаете очередной коммит:

```
git commit -m'deleted files from blablabla'
```

## Как удалять сразу на диске и в Git

Можно удалять файлы из рабочей директории и индексировать удаление в Git с помощью одной [команды git rm](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-rm):

```
git rm -- <file1> <file2> <file3>
git rm -r -- <directory1>
```